# USB Hub Power Exceeded displaylink - works after restart

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, lenovo-laptop, displaylink

#### Problem

I get "USB Hub Power Exceeded" whenever I have to reconnect my USB display adapter while the computer is on.

What I currently do is to restart my computer and the display adapter is back working. I'm sure I was able to do this before but I had the OS reinstalled.

#### What I've done:

- Power Management - Disabled USB selective suspend while plugged
  in
- Unchecked "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save
  power" under USB device drivers
- Updated Intel USB 3.0 Extensible host

#### Question

How can I reconnect my usb display adapter while powered on and get it working?

Devices: Lenovo T450 - Windows 7 64 bit
Monoprice Display adapter usb to dvi - displaylink drivers

Comment: Do you have EHCI/XHCI Hand-Off enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: I can't modify the bios it being a company device but I wasn't able to find that option either.

Comment: The error could be because the adapter is drawing more power from the USB port than the computer can provide to power itself up - though I don't know why that would happen or solutions to this other than buying a powered USB hub

Comment: That's what the computer is saying and I'm questioning that case because it works fine when plugged in before booting, it was drawing more power than the computer could provide it shouldn't work at all. Questions is why do I get a power exceeded error when I unplug it and plug it in with the computer on? Would it be drawing any more power than it was before?

Answer (score 0):

A powered USB hub is definitely the answer.

- http://www.skivatech.com/power/octofire
- [http://www.amazon.com/Upgraded-Anker-SuperSpeed-Including-Charging/dp/B005NGQWL2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005NGQWL2)

Or maybe try a USB power injector.